# Typedef shares object alias locally but not globally however at tag may share it locally or globally if not synonymous with typedefed, why?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, scope, typedef

Here is a sketch of the issue (with the error codes clang is throwing out):

Typedef and struct def of tag;

```
typedef struct tag {int tag;} tag;
```

This works just fine:

```
struct tag {int tag;} tag;
```

whereas either of these typedefs error:

```
typedef struct {int tag;} tag;

/*or*/

typedef struct tag {int tag;} tag;

/*and then this following code fails from either of the two 
previous typedefs which the compiler errors about as being 
redeclared as as different kind of symbol. Not allowed to share 
typedef with object id:*/

tag tag;
```

Compiler errors on the two globals when a typedef/tag of same name is specified:

```
/*error: redefinition of 'tag' as different kind of symbol:*/

    struct tag tag = {1};
```

OK, masks global tag and uses it's global val

```
    int main (void) {

    struct tag tag = {tag.tag + 1};
    
    //Works fine, but why locally and not globally?

    tag tag = {2};

    printf("tag: %d\n", tag);
    }
```

Output is:

`tag: 3`

A few questions:

1. What is the difference between a tag and a typedef? It seems that a typedef reserves storage for an identifier whereas the struct tag defines the interpretation of storage.
2. Why does using a tagged object support synonymous tag-object globally but can not use a typedef-object synonym globally?
3. Why is the typedef and tag allowed to declare a single object of the same name at some scope?
4. If the definition were:

   `struct tag {struct tag * tagA, * tagB}  tag = {.tagA = &tagB, .tagB = malloc(sizeof tagB};`

   How would that make any difference practically or significantly for application?
5. What is the relationship between the tag and the object id? It seem like a clue since typedef id is prohibited globally from being synonymous with the typedef-object id yet it is acceptable locally...
6. What else needs to be known about this subject, for instance union or pointer-related?

Comment: And what  is the error the compiler issues for the global declaration?

Comment: You need to learn about [name spaces.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/name_space) Also note that using the same identifier for multiple things can be all kinds of confusing.

Comment: This is the type of question that feels easy to answer, but is actually very difficult because of the misguided presuppositions in the question itself.

Comment: @Vlad: I updated the code example with the compiler errors in the notes at the beginning, one for the tag and another for the typedef.

Answer (score 9):

The issues revolve around namespaces and scopes — see [§6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3) and [§6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1) in the C11 standard.

> 1. What is the difference between a tag and a typedef? It seems that a typedef reserves storage for an identifier whereas the struct tag defines the interpretation of storage.

No; not at all.  The line `typedef struct tag {int tag;} tag;` defines a structure type with a tag (`struct tag`), and declares an alias for `struct tag` called `tag`.  That alias is in the 'ordinary identifiers' namespace, the same as other variables and function and typedef names. There is no storage reserved anywhere at this time.

The structure type can be referred to as either `struct tag` or just `tag` after that line.  If you had used `typedef struct Value { int value; } Value_t;`, you'd have a type `struct Value` with alias `Value_t` — the name differentiation makes it easier to discuss.

> 2. Why does using a tagged object support synonymous tag-object globally but can not use a typedef-object synonym globally?

It's not clear what you mean here.  Scope is a problem when using `tag` so extensively.  Inside a function, you could write either one of these statements:

```
struct tag tag = { 1 };
tag tag = { 1 };
```

These both create a variable `tag` and have the side-effect of hiding the typedef `tag` (but you'd still be able to use `struct tag` to define more variables).  At file scope, you have defined `tag` as a type alias via the `typedef` (in the 'ordinary identifiers' namespace); you can't redefine it to mean something else — so neither `tag tag;` nor `struct tag tag;` is acceptable because the name `tag` is an alias for the type.

> 3. Why is the typedef and tag allowed to declare a single object of the same name at some scope?

They don't.  The `struct tag` is in the tags namespace.  The type alias `tag` is in the ordinary identifiers namespace.  These are distinct.  You also have a member `tag` in the per-structure member namespace; you could have a label `tag` in the label namespace.

> 4. If the definition were:
>
>    ```
>    struct tag {struct tag *tagA, *tagB; } tag = { .tagA = &tagB, .tagB = malloc(sizeof tagB) };
>    ```
>
>    How would that make any difference practically or significantly for application?

It wouldn't compile because neither `&tagB` nor `sizeof tagB` has a defined meaning.  Assuming that is resolved, the use of the names `struct tag` and `tag` wouldn't change.  You could create linked lists or trees or other data structures using the pointers.

> 5. What is the relationship between the tag and the object id? It seems like a clue since typedef id is prohibited globally from being synonymous with the typedef-object id yet it is acceptable locally...

It all depends on scopes and namespaces.  A new statement block `{ … }` starts a new scope; you can hide names in the outer scopes by redefining them in the inner scope.  (It's not a particularly good idea to do that, but you can.  Using GCC or Clang, the `-Wshadow` option will warn you when you hide a variable by redefining it in an inner scope.) You ran into problems because you tried to define `tag` to mean too many things at once at the file scope.

> 6. What else needs to be known about this subject, for instance union or pointer-related?

You really only need to know that tags for structures, unions and enumerations all share a single tag namespace (the standard has a footnote that says: "There is only one name space for tags even though three are possible").

You can use:

```
struct tagname;
```

to indicate that there is a type `struct tagname`, and you can define pointers to that type even without any details of what is inside the type.  This can be a good way to hide information — a public header might say the type exists and use it in the interfaces to the functions of a module without revealing what's inside.  The client code can then only pass pointers to the type around.  The implementation of the module would have the definition of the type in a private header (or in a single source file if the module is small enough).  Without the details, the client programmer cannot (legitimately) access the data in the structure — it is called an "opaque type" for a good reason.

Pointers to the types are pointers to the types; they don't change anything.  You should be leery of [using `typedef` for pointer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/15168).

Answer (score 3):

C has four types of *name spaces*. Names (identifiers) are handled separately in each name space. The four types are:

- Label names, for `goto` labels. There is one name space of this type.
- Tags of structures, unions, and enumerations. This is the name that may appear after the keyword `struct`, `union`, or `enum`. There is one name space of this type.
- Members of structures or unions. Each structure or union has its own name space of this type.
- All other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers. There is one name space of this type.

An identifier also has a *scope*, which is the region of source code over which its declaration applies.

In `typedef struct tag {int tag;} tag;`, the first `tag` is in the tag name space. The second `tag` is in the member name space for the `struct tag` structure. The third `tag` is in the ordinary name space. So these names are all known simultaneously, but they are in different name spaces. For this declaration outside of any function, they have file scope; each name is known until the end of the translation unit.

> `//struct tag tag = {1};`

This would declare `tag` to be an object of type `struct tag`, and that `tag` would be in the ordinary name space with file scope. However, there is already a `tag` in the ordinary name space with file scope, the `typedef` declared above. So the compiler would complain that this redeclaration of `tag` is invalid.

> `//tag tag;`

Same as above. The first `tag` is using the known type `tag`, not declaring it, so that is fine. But the second `tag` would attempt to declare `tag` as an identifier for an object in the ordinary name space with file scope, but that identifier is already known as a type in the ordinary name space with file scope.

> `tag tag = {2};`

This is inside the function, so it declares `tag` as an identifier for an object in the ordinary name space with file scope. This is allowed; you can have a new declaration in a new scope of an identifier that is already known in an enclosing scope. The new declaration hides the old one, until the end of the scope of the new identifier.

In this declaration, the first `tag` refers to the type known as `tag`, because that declaration is not yet hidden. Then the second `tag` is declared with a new meaning, after which the first meaning is hidden.

> 1. What is the difference between a tag and a typedef? It seems that a typedef reserves storage for an identifier whereas the struct tag defines the interpretation of storage.

A structure tag is put into and looked up in the tag name space. A typedef name is put into and looked up in the ordinary name space.

> 2. Why does using a tagged object support synonymous tag-object globally but can not use a typedef-object synonym globally?

The structure tags exist in a separate name space, so declaring an object with the same name as a tag does not conflict. Typedef aliases exist in the ordinary name space, so declaring an object with the same name in the same scope conflicts.

> 3. Why is the typedef and tag allowed to declare a single object of the same name at some scope?

In a nested scope, you are allowed to declare names that hide declarations in an enclosing scope.

> 4. If the definition were:…

This question is unclear and seems to be a different subject than the name spaces and scopes of identifiers.

> 5. What is the relationship between the tag and the object id?

They are separated by being in separate name spaces. There is no inherent relationship.

> 6. What else needs to be known about this subject, for instance union or pointer-related?

Further information is in clauses 6.2.1, 6.2.2, and 6.2.3 of the 2018 C standard.

Answer (score 0):

The summary of issues addressed led to these answers:

1. **Complpexity of Expression**

   A complex definition cause an incorrect interpretation of the concepts
   involved. To resolve this, address the elements in components:

*Instead of:*

```
typedef struct tag {int tag;} tag;
```

do it in chunks by declaring the type, define the typedef by defining the structure, then declare the object and define its values:

```
    typdef struct tag tag; /*Forward definition of typedef from tag*/
    struct tag {int tag;}; /*Tag definition*/
    tag tag                /*Type name allocation*/
    /*or*/ 
    struct tag tag         /*Tag name allocation*/
```

2. **Scope and Namespace**

The considerations regarding the alias are the scope and namespace. An
identifier also has a scope, which is the region of source code over which
its declaration applies. A new statement block { … } starts a new scope;
you can hide names in the outer scopes by redefining them in the inner
scope. The scopes may be nested and each nest may mask a previous object,
tag and/or type from a previous but not necessarily immediate level:

```
    `/*Global tag in scope(active):*/`

    `/*Defines function w/tag but global tag still active, not masked.*/
    void structure() {
        struct tag tag;
    }

    /*Main routine establishes a new scope and masks global if present:*/
    int main () {
        tag tag;

        /*Struct expands to its own block and within, may mask priors:*/
        structure();
        /*End of structure scope, reverts to main block.*/

        /*An explicit sub_block that can mask as well:*/
        sub_block: {
            struct tag tag;
            /*A function call here may mask the sub_block*/
            structure();
            /*Function mask out of scope now, reverts to sub_block.*/
        }
        /*End of sub_block, reverts to main block.*/
    }`
  `/*End of main block, reverts to file then global if not present.*/`
```

Just like a compound expression block, a struct establishes a new scope with each level of structure it contains masking the previous if needed:

```
struct tag {     /*Establishes first scope for use of tag object.*/
    struct tag { /*Establishes second scope for use of tag object.*/
        ...;     /*continues to nest as desired...*/
    };
} tag;
```

C has four types of name spaces. Names (identifiers) are handled separately in each name space. The four types are:

```
 1. Label names, for goto labels. There is one name space of this type.
 2. Tags of structures, unions, and enumerations. This is the name that 
    may appear after the keyword struct, union, or enum. There is one name
    space of this type.
 3. Members of structures or unions. Each structure or union has its own
    name space of this type.
 4. All other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers. There is one
    name space of this type.
```

3. Types vs Tags

   Types are defined from the primitives(int, float, char, void *, etc.) in
   structures. A structure may be accessed by a type or tag however a tag
   defines the internal arrangement of the primitives and may be accessed
   later for object definitions as in the following object decleration list:

   `struct tag object, *reference, list[], (function)(), etc...;`

   to reserve storage of specified type. Note that an object list is a list of
   named regions of storeage which is not the same as a type definition.

   A typedef may be used for the same purpose however it also allows
   specification of synonyms for the single tag that is the root of storage.
   These typedefs may be defined with arrays, references and argument groups
   which reserve the names as types to create objects from, not objects
   themselves. The list implements the types of:

   0. struct tag
   1. tag
   2. tag type reference
   3. function reference returning a tag reference
   4. array of pointers to functions returning a tag reference:

   `typedef struct tag` `tag_t,`
   `* ptr_tag,`
   `(*ptr_func)(),`
   `array_func[],`
   `...;`

Unions and enums get even more interesting...please send me any good articles on use of unions, structures, organization or other solid designs principles!